# How to allow non-root user to write to ZFS external USB flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, usb-drive, zfs

In Ubuntu 20.04, I installed the `zfsutils-linux` package and formatted an external USB thumbdrive to use ZFS (`sudo zpool create mypool /dev/sdb`). However, the mounted pool at `/mypool` is only writable by root. I tried to export (`sudo zpool export mypool`) and reimport (`sudo zpool import mypool`) the pool, but `/mypool` is still owned by root and has permissions `drwxr-xr-x`. Is there a way to configure ZFS to allow non-root users to write to a mounted external USB drive?

Answer (score 3):

*While the pool is mounted*, change the ownership of the root directory of the pool to your normal user account:

```
sudo chown $(whoami): /mypool
```

After that, you can create subdirectories and files as usual - and since you are the owner, you will be able to set the permissions however you like.